# Saving Tiles in an irregular grid

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I have a grid, which the user can expand as he wishes. Since I don't know how big the grid will end up (and many tiles will stay empty) a two dimensional array (`Tile[][] gird`) wouldn't work. But I feel like just adding Tiles to a list (`List<Tile> grid`) can't be the best way, since when I want to get a Tile I have to search for it every time (`grid.SingleOrDefault(t => t.x == _x && t.y == _y)`). Which is ofcourse not ideal.

Is there a method which e.g. sorts the `List<Tile>` in a way that it's faster to accesss a given tile?

[image]

Comment: When you say "saving", do you mean serializing to a saved game file on disc? Or are you just looking for in-memory representations?

Comment: @DMGregory Just for memory. But at some point also for saving on a disk

Comment: These will likely have two very different solutions: the in memory representation should be optimized for fast random access and ease of expanding. The on-disc representation doesn't need those features, but would benefit from compactness. So you'll probably want to ask about each problem separately. I'd recommend using keywords like "storing" "representing" or "data structure" for the in-memory case, rather than "saving" which suggests the serialize-to-disc case.

Comment: Maybe a [dictionary](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/dictionary-in-C-Sharp/)?

Comment: Are you traversing the tiles from tile to tile or do you need to find at any given moment any of them?

Comment: @Mangata I was thinking about it. But aren't dics quite resource intensive as well?

Comment: @Zibelas I need to be albe to access any tile at any point.

Comment: The time complexity of dict query is O(1), and the time complexity of array query is O(n). This is a standard space-for-time strategy.Yes it will take up more memory, but the benefits are obvious.

Comment: @Mangata remember that big-O notation tells you *asymptotic* complexity, meaning how the work scales as n gets larger. It does not let you compare the absolute costs for a fixed n. In practice, linearly searching an array can be faster than a dictionary lookup even for n values in the low thousands, depending on the details of the implementation/hardware etc. That's not to say dictionaries are bad, but the trade-off is not quite so "obvious" as the big-O analysis makes it seem.

Comment: @DMGregory Some languages will directly use linear search when the dict length is less than a certain value, which is an optimization term. There is really no advantage to dict when n is small, but it is suitable for many more cases. From the point of view of ease of use it is better. I think.